# Making a button that saves lists for the next time the program is run

Tags: c#, windows, list, save

I'm making a windows form application. It is a word generator that generates a random word from a default list that can also be modified by user input. I'm looking for a way to make it so that a button will save the lists so that the next time the user runs the application, they will have the same lists from before. txtaddverb is the text box for user input. The missing buttons do the same thing only for a list of nouns, adjectives, and adverbs.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
  public class Lists
    {
        public static List<string> verbList = new List<string>() {"eat", "scramble", "slap", "stimulate"};

        public static Random randomverb = new Random();
    }


public string pickRandomVerb()

        {
            return Lists.verbList[Lists.randomverb.Next(0, Lists.verbList.Count)];
        }

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (Lists.verbList.Count > 0) verb.Text = pickRandomVerb();
        }

public void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            Lists.verbList.Add(txtaddverb.Text);
            txtaddverb.Clear();
        } 

public void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            Lists.verbList.Clear();
            verb.Clear();
            txtaddverb.Clear();
        }

//below is the button that I want to save the list

public static void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            //need help here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Where do you want to save the input? In a text-file? In a database?

Example of saving to a textfile

```
        // create a writer and open the file
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("date.txt");

        // write a line of text to the file
        tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);

        // close the stream
        tw.Close();
```

Comment: Whatever would be the most simple.

Answer (score 0):

To write a `List<string>` into a file:

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, verbList);
```

This will create the file if it doesn't exist or overwrite it otherwise.

Read it from the file:

```
List<string> verbList = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If this project is more for personal use then you could just write the list to a text file and read it back in when the program loads.  The streamreader and streamwriter classes could be implemented for that. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903247%28v=vs.71%29.aspx for some sample code.

If multiple people will be using your app, I'd say saving the list to a database would be a better solution.  Here's a good place to start http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/31314-sql-basics-in-c%23/#/  If you don't have SQL server the tutorial can be adjusted for something like MS Access.  (you'd be using System.Data.OleDb instead of System.Data.SqlClient)

There are a lot of articles out there going over reading and writing information to text files or databases.  Do a little searching and you should be able to find something that suits your needs if the two links I posted don't have what you're looking for.